# Is it possible to change the user interface images of a library from application project in android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have library aar file.That aar file is added to the my application project.it is successfully added without giving any errors.now i trying to change the user interface of the libary from application.is it possible or not?if yes,how to change the user interface of the libary?

Comment: that completely depends on how the library is implemented.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Thanks for reply,library is created by me only but how to change the background image through application?

Comment: get the library's view, and call `setBackgroundImage` method on it. Again, the way to get the view depends on the library implementation. Also you could try to override library resources with your application, if the background is declared through XML